# How to display crystal report in c# in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I was creating a table like this. From this I want to display all dates score only for `rollno 1` in crystal report. How do I do that?

table like this shown below.

```
rollno     name          score      date
1          x               12       1-2-2011
2          y               20       2-2-2011
3          z               25       3-2-2011
4          A               13       3-5-2011
5          B               15       5-6-2012
1          X               20       1-2-2012
2          y               18       1-3-2012
3          z               15       8-3-2012
4          A               12       9-5-2013
1          x               3        9-1-2013
1          x               50       9-1-2010
2          y               15       9-1-2013 
2          y                6       10-4-2010
```

---

Accept reprt

```
         name:x    roll:1

          2010-2011|2011-12|  2012-13|2013-14

               50          12      20        3
```

Comment: this may help http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm

Comment: thanks .i was tried this is working but it display all the rollnos in a table .i want to display the details of a particular person only in the report..ex: 1 x 12 1-2-2011 ,1 X 20 1-2-2012 ,1 x 3 9-1-2013, 1 x 50 9-1-2010

Comment: thank i want to display date range as how above in accepted report

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think What you are trying to do here is group on basis of your Roll No
For that you may use GroupExpert(RightClick on Report-->Insert-->Group) and you may group it with your Roll No
take a look at [Grouping MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227413%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

a simple example has been explained here
[Grouping Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ea36c5/crystal-reports-grouping-pattern-1/)

You can repeat your groups at different pages as well

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for helped me .i was done this. but i want to display only one person  from that table in crystal report how i can do this?.help me

Comment: table:1
rollno   test1  test2
1          20     30
2          15     10
3          16     18
4          19     50      
5          20     20
form above table when i was click on table 1 on rollno 1 it should matches with the table (plz seen above table)with same roll no 1 .and genterate data for only rollno 1 in crystal report plz help me urgent

Comment: thanku very much i got it. but i want to dispaly date range also help me urgent to me any hint

Comment: thanks but "The formula cannot be evalutaed at the time Specfied " this type of error is coming how? help me urgent

Answer (score 0):

if you have to select Date Range in crystal report for that you have to make it first
For that we make a formula
you just create a new Parameter field, set the type to "Date" and make sure the "Allow range vales" option i set to true.  With the parameter field created, you need to add a record select formula that reads like this...

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

DateTimeVar date1;

DateTimeVar date2;

date1:=Minimum({?DateRange Parameter});

date2:=Maximum({?DateRange Parameter});

IF totext(Date(date1)) = "" AND totext(Date(date2)) <> ""

THEN

" Before " + totext(Date(date2))

 ELSE IF totext(Date(date1)) <> "" AND totext(Date(date2)) = ""

  THEN

  " After " + totext(Date(date1))

  ELSE IF totext(Date(date1)) <> "" AND totext(Date(date2)) <> ""

  THEN

  " Between " + totext(Date(date1)) + " AND " + totext(Date(date2))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but "The formula cannot be evalutaed at the time Specfied " this type of error is coming how? help me urgent

Comment: other wise help me how to display report like above one . i was done half but only thing i was not getting date range like above one help me